# IFileOperationでWPD（スマホ）のSDカードフォルダ内でファイルコピーできない

Tags: c#

COMインターフェースのIFileOperationを使っています。
CopyItemsでファイルをコピーしようとしましたが、
スマホ等のWPDのフォルダ内でファイルをコピー、貼付けしようとすると
「予期しないエラーのため、ファイルをコピーできません。このエラーが再発する場合は、エラーコードを使用して、この問題についてのヘルプを検索してください。」
「エラー0x800700AA：要求されたリソースは使用中です。」
とメッセージが出てコピーできません。

WPDのSDカードから`C:\`、および`C:\`からWPDのSDカードへのコピーはできます。

対処方法や代替方法をご存じでしたらお教えください。

ソースはC#で以下のようなものです。

```
string dstPathName = @"::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}\\\?\usb#vid_xxxx&pid_xxxx#xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx#{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\SDカード\mydata"

//dataにはクリップボードのデータ。スマホのSDカード内のファイルをエクスプローラで右クリック、コピーした状態。
IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
Guid IID_IShellItem = typeof(IShellItem).GUID;
IntPtr pDstFullIDL = ILCreateFromPath(dstFolderName);
IShellItem dstItem = null;
SHCreateItemFromIDList(pDstFullIDL, ref IID_IShellItem, out dstItem);

IFileOperation fo = (IFileOperation)new FileOperation();
fo.CopyItems(data, dstItem);
fo.SetOperationFlags(FileOperationFlags.FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION);

try{fo.PerformOperations();}
catch{}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
[ComImport]
[Guid("3ad05575-8857-4850-9277-11b85bdb8e09")]
public class FileOperation
{
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("947aab5f-0a5c-4c13-b4d6-4bf7836fc9f8")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
internal interface IFileOperation
{
    uint Advise(IFileOperationProgressSink pfops);
    void Unadvise(uint dwCookie);

    void SetOperationFlags(FileOperationFlags dwOperationFlags);
    void SetProgressMessage([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszMessage);
    void SetProgressDialog([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object popd);
    void SetProperties([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pproparray);
    void SetOwnerWindow(uint hwndParent);

    void ApplyPropertiesToItem(IShellItem psiItem);
    void ApplyPropertiesToItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkItems);

    void RenameItem(IShellItem psiItem, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName,
        IFileOperationProgressSink pfopsItem);

    void RenameItems(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object pUnkItems,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName);

    void MoveItem(
        IShellItem psiItem,
        IShellItem psiDestinationFolder,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName,
        IFileOperationProgressSink pfopsItem);

    void MoveItems(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkItems,
        IShellItem psiDestinationFolder);

    int CopyItem(
        IShellItem psiItem,
        IShellItem psiDestinationFolder,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszCopyName,
        IFileOperationProgressSink pfopsItem);

    int CopyItems(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkItems,
        IShellItem psiDestinationFolder);

    void DeleteItem(
        IShellItem psiItem,
        IFileOperationProgressSink pfopsItem);

    void DeleteItems([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] object punkItems);

    uint NewItem(
        IShellItem psiDestinationFolder,
        FileAttributes dwFileAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszTemplateName,
        IFileOperationProgressSink pfopsItem);

    void PerformOperations();

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    bool GetAnyOperationsAborted();
}

[ComImport]
[Guid("04b0f1a7-9490-44bc-96e1-4296a31252e2")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IFileOperationProgressSink
{
    void StartOperations();
    void FinishOperations(uint hrResult);

    void PreRenameItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName);
    void PostRenameItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName,
        uint hrRename, IShellItem psiNewlyCreated);

    void PreMoveItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, IShellItem psiDestinationFolder,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName);
    void PostMoveItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, IShellItem psiDestinationFolder,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName, uint hrMove, IShellItem psiNewlyCreated);

    void PreCopyItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, IShellItem psiDestinationFolder, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName);
    void PostCopyItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, IShellItem psiDestinationFolder, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName,
        uint hrCopy, IShellItem psiNewlyCreated);

    void PreDeleteItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem);
    void PostDeleteItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiItem, uint hrDelete, IShellItem psiNewlyCreated);

    void PreNewItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiDestinationFolder, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName);
    void PostNewItem(uint dwFlags, IShellItem psiDestinationFolder, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszNewName,
         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszTemplateName, uint dwFileAttributes,
         uint hrNew, IShellItem psiNewItem);

    void UpdateProgress(uint iWorkTotal, uint iWorkSoFar);

    void ResetTimer();
    void PauseTimer();
    void ResumeTimer();
}

[Flags]
public enum FileOperationFlags : uint
{
    FOF_SILENT = 0x0004,                
    FOF_NOCONFIRMATION = 0x0010,        
    FOF_ALLOWUNDO = 0x0040,             
    FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS = 0x0100,        
    FOF_NOERRORUI = 0x0400,             
    FOF_WANTNUKEWARNING = 0x4000,       
    FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION = 0x0008,
}
```

Comment: Explorerでは同等の操作は実現できているのでしょうか？

Comment: Explorerでは転送していますといったダイアログが出てくるのでIFileOperationとは別のAPIを使っているようです。それが何というAPIかわかるとありがたいのですが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

試しておらず当てずっぽうですが。

[`IFileOperation::CopyItems`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation-copyitems)は`IDataObject`も受け付けますがそれ以外にも`IShellItemArray`や`IEnumShellItems`も受け付けています。[`SHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-shcreateshellitemarrayfromdataobject)で`IShellItemArray`に変換しこれを渡してみるのはどうでしょうか？
なお、ここで出てくる`IDataObject`はC#においては[`System.Windows.Forms.IDataObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.idataobject?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)**ではなく**、[`System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IDataObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.idataobject?view=net-6.0)を指します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実は先にSHCreateShellItemArrayFromIDListsを使用したバージョンで試し、だめだったのでIDataObjectに変更して、それでもだめだったので質問しました。

Comment: @user49158 解決したのでしょうか？ だめだった、と書かれていたので少し疑問が残ります。

Comment: お教えいただいたSHCreateShellItemArrayFromDataObjectで試してみましたが、発生するメッセージは同じでした。IFileOperationに正しくコピー元ファイル、コピー先フォルダの情報は渡せているようなので、IFileOperation内部の問題のようにも思いました。

Answer (score 1):

NuGetのMediaDevicesというライブラリでアクセス出来るようです。

[How to read files on Android phone from C# program on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026799/how-to-read-files-on-android-phone-from-c-sharp-program-on-windows-7)
[MediaDevices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediaDevices/)

内部では、[WPD Application Programming Interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/wpd-application-programming-interface) が使用されているようです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみます。